# "No permission to access" an apache server on a virtual machine

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, virtual-machines

I'm running WAMP on a Win7 virtual machine. I'm trying to access the server via my web browser, but it's not working.

Inside the VM, the IP address is shown to be 192.168.31.132

Going to `http://192.168.31.132/` however, delivers a 403 Forbidden error.

I don't know what happened to cause this. I tried this right after installing the software, default settings all the way.

I turned off Windows Firewall on the VM, didn't change anything.

So I wonder, what setting in Apache is making this happen?

EDIT: things *did* work after I put the server online...

Question solved

Comment: did you check permissions of the www-data/htdocs folder? perhaps the user running Apache has no access to that folder, you can set the folder to everyone (read) as a quick test.

Comment: That folder does not exist. I'm not running linux, I'm not working with a custom Apache install. I'm using WAMP, as stated in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as Luma pointed out, are most likely the file permissions on www-data/htdocs. Try that first.

If that fails, enable verbose logging in Apache (`LogLevel debug` in the config, reload/restart Apache), then trigger the error and look into the logs to see what is going wrong.

If you 're still stuck, edit your question with this additional info, then maybe we can help.

Comment: I can't find any setting with the word "verbose" in it.

Comment: @WebDevHobo: That were just my words. The setting to change is `LogLevel`, and the value is `debug`. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#loglevel